# Unable to connect to SQL server after update

Tags: networking, server, sql

I updated my server today with all pending update and after reboot I was unable to connect to SQL server. Prior to reboot I've also enabled the firewall but now it's disabled again and server is after another reboot. When I try to connect locally using

```
sqlcmd -S localhost
```

I get error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Server itself is up and running:

```
hyperqbe@slaro:/etc$ sudo systemctl status mssql-server
[sudo] hasło użytkownika hyperqbe:
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-08 15:06:28 CEST; 19min ago
     Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 7259 (sqlservr)
    Tasks: 158
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─7259 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
           └─7288 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

sie 08 15:06:38 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [95B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:38 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [91B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:38 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [145B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:38 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [61B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:39 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [96B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:39 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [66B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:40 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [96B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:40 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [100B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:40 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [71B blob data]
sie 08 15:06:40 slaro sqlservr[7259]: [124B blob data]
```

I'm unable to connect remotely from other machine as well:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------
Cannot connect to 192.168.1.141.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Istniejące połączenie zostało gwałtownie zamknięte przez zdalnego hosta.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=10054&LinkId=20476
```

As far as I know there were no errors during update process.

Here are the last entries from errorlog:

```
2019-08-08 15:06:34.89 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (CTP3.2) - 15.0.1800.32 (X64)
        Jul 17 2019 21:29:33
        Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
        Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) <X64>
2019-08-08 15:06:34.89 Server      UTC adjustment: 2:00
2019-08-08 15:06:34.89 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.89 Server      All rights reserved.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.89 Server      Server process ID is 32.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.89 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.89 Server      Registry startup parameters:
         -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
         -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
         -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2019-08-08 15:06:34.90 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 4 cores per socket and 4 logical processors per socket, 4 total logical processors; using 4 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.90 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.90 Server      Detected 12800 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.90 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2019-08-08 15:06:34.90 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2019-08-08 15:06:35.01 Server      Buffer pool extension is not supported on Linux platform.
2019-08-08 15:06:35.02 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 2097152 bytes for 1963331 hashPages.
2019-08-08 15:06:35.16 Server      Default collation: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033)
2019-08-08 15:06:35.69 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2019-08-08 15:06:35.99 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ['1.0 1.1 1.2']. Allowed TLS ciphers are ['ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'].
2019-08-08 15:06:36.01 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1,
2019-08-08 15:06:36.07 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2019-08-08 15:06:36.07 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0 Active CPU mask: 0x000000000000000f:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.11 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.17 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.37 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.57 Server      [INFO] Created Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'

2019-08-08 15:06:36.58 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.59 Server      Total Log Writer threads: 2. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.72 Server      clflushopt is selected for pmem flush operation.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.72 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.97 spid11s     [1]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2019-08-08 15:06:36.98 spid11s     Starting up database 'master'.
2019-08-08 15:06:37.58 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized.
2019-08-08 15:06:37.77 spid11s     SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:37.78 spid11s     SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.05 Server      Failed to verify the Authenticode signature of 'C:\binn\secforwarder.dll'. Signature verification of SQL Server DLLs will be skipped. Genuine copies of SQL Server are signed. Failure to verify the Authenticode signature might indicate that this is not an authentic release of SQL Server. Install a genuine copy of SQL Server or contact customer support.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.11 spid11s     SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2019-08-08 15:06:38.27 spid11s     Server name is 'slaro'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.29 spid29s     Always On: The availability replica manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.29 spid29s     Always On: The availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server to allow client connections. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.30 spid11s     [4]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.30 spid11s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.32 spid12s     [32767]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.32 spid12s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.33 spid12s     The resource database build version is 15.00.1800. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.36 spid12s     [3]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.36 spid12s     Starting up database 'model'.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.40 Server      Failed to verify the Authenticode signature of 'C:\binn\msoledbsql.dll'. Signature verification of SQL Server DLLs will be skipped. Genuine copies of SQL Server are signed. Failure to verify the Authenticode signature might indicate that this is not an authentic release of SQL Server. Install a genuine copy of SQL Server or contact customer support.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.48 spid28s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.51 Server      Error: 37308, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.51 Server      Loaded None enclave for always encrypted.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.51 spid28s     Server is listening on [ 192.168.1.141 <ipv4> 1433].
2019-08-08 15:06:38.54 spid28s     Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.54 spid28s     Error: 39002, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.54 spid28s     SQL failed to boot extensibility for error code 0x80070005.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.55 spid28s     InitializeXdbPkgLauncher failed. ErrorCode: 0x80004005.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.55 spid28s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:06:38.85 spid12s     Clearing tempdb database.
2019-08-08 15:06:39.88 spid12s     [2]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2019-08-08 15:06:39.89 spid12s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2019-08-08 15:06:40.26 spid29s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2019-08-08 15:06:40.26 spid29s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2019-08-08 15:06:40.27 spid29s     Service Broker manager has started.
2019-08-08 15:06:40.27 spid11s     Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2019-08-08 15:27:16.30 spid55      [5]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1.
2019-08-08 15:27:16.30 spid55      Starting up database 'ProgramMagazynowy'.
2019-08-08 15:27:16.53 spid55      Parallel redo is started for database 'ProgramMagazynowy' with worker pool size [2].
2019-08-08 15:27:16.73 spid55      Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'ProgramMagazynowy' with worker pool size [2].
```

It may have something to do with ODBC driver. I was able to enable logging and found this:

```
[ODBC][29210][1565333226.007247][SQLDriverConnectW.c][290]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x8c90e0
                        Window Hdl = (nil)
                        Str In = [DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER={192.168.1.141};Trusted_Connection={YES};WSID={slaro};APP={SQLCMD};][length = 113 (SQL_NTS)]
                        Str Out = (nil)
                        Str Out Max = 0
                        Str Out Ptr = (nil)
                        Completion = 0
                UNICODE Using encoding ASCII 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' and UNICODE 'UTF-16LE'
```

According to [Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#troubleshooting-connection-problems)

> If the ASCII character encoding is not UTF-8, there is more than one
>   Driver Manager installed and your application is using the wrong one,
>   or the Driver Manager was not built correctly.

## In my case it's 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' so there has to be something wrong. I will further review the articles suggested in documentation but right now I don't know how to confirm that I indeed have two drivers installed and how to remove one.

EDIT:

odbcinst lists only one driver:

```
hyperqbe@slaro:/etc$ odbcinst -q -d
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
```

This part seems to be fine. I'm not sure if I have my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini defined correctly.

```
hyperqbe@slaro:/etc$ cat odbc.ini
[slaro]
Driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
Servername=192.168.1.141

hyperqbe@slaro:/etc$ cat odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.4.so.1.1
UsageCount=1
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/home/hyperqbe/odbc.log
```

=======================================

EDIT ((ufw details per request)):

```
hyperqbe@slaro:~$ sudo ufw status
[sudo] hasło użytkownika hyperqbe:
Stan: aktywny

Do                         Działanie   Z
--                         ---------   -
27                         ALLOW       Anywhere
1433                       ALLOW       Anywhere
1434                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8686                       ALLOW       Anywhere
27 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1433 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1434 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
8686 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

22/tcp                     REJECT OUT  Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                REJECT OUT  Anywhere (v6)

hyperqbe@slaro:~$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:27
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:27
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ms-sql-s
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ms-sql-s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ms-sql-m
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ms-sql-m
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8686
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:8686

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh reject-with tcp-reset
```

I've found [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265913/error-tcp-provider-error-code-0x2746-during-the-sql-setup-in-linux-through-te) suggesting that problem might be caused by python.

Comment: Can't be sure but you can try downgrading [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265913/error-tcp-provider-error-code-0x2746-during-the-sql-setup-in-linux-through-te/57343207#57343207)

Comment: Tried that today, didn't work. Also tried reinstalling the odbc packages and sql-tools, didn't help as well.

Looks like I will have to do a clean installation.

Comment: I have the same exact problem and cannot connect neither locally nor remotely.

I have a small web application that i use locally and i also connected remotely from a windows machine with Management studio.

I used to be able to connect from both locations but now neither works.

Comment: I'm reinstalling the mssql-server now. I hope it was some dependency broken or glitch in database (I've completely cleared /var/opt/mssql/data).

Comment: Ok, something changed - I ran the "sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup" on old instance, I've been choosing "Express" edition, but I was still getting "This is an evaluation version.  There are [161] days left in the evaluation period." message. But this time it was followed by "The licensing PID was successfully processed. The new edition is [Express Edition]."

Comment: Fresh install didn't work :( I'm still getting the error:
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Client unable to establish connection.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the output to `sudo ufw status` and to `iptables --list` and then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby Output added as requested.

Comment: what happens if you type `sudo ufw disable`?  does it magically start working?  If not: type `sudo ufw enable` immediately afterwards.

Comment: Same result unfortunately. Unfortunately I can't go back to previous version of mssql as my database is already in v15 and it's impossible to restore newer to older.

Comment: Downgrade to SQL14 didn't help, still getting same error. It must be some of the dependencies that was installed during update. Unless there are some hidden firewall settings that prevail despite ufw being disabled.

Comment: I'm sure this is not your case, but I will still share mine - maybe someone stumbles on it. I also, after the mssql upgrade wasn't able any more to start the server. It turns out it was because, BEFORE the update, my MSDB database was broken, so after the upgrade, the server was restarted and the restart failed. It would have failed if I restarted for any other reason as well. After some issues, I finally figured out how to rebuild the MSDB system database: by rerunning the `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` procedure

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265913/error-tcp-provider-error-code-0x2746-during-the-sql-setup-in-linux-through-te/57343207#57343207), this worked for me. It seems to be a problem with openssl version, something that was fixed by microsoft on CU10 for MSSQL and gives back with CU16.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not connect to my SQL server anymore suddenly. It was because of missing space. So I made space free and restartet the apache2 service (or restart the whole server if it does not work).